# Make WSL register GPU as the correct GPU and not a microsoft driver

Tags: linux, windows, drivers, gpu, wsl2

I am trying to run a cuda (qubic.li - Client) program on linux using WSL. I have two main problems.

1. my GPU is AMD (I get around this using ZLUDA)
2. WSL does not register my GPU as AMD meaning that ZLUDA does not kick in (at least that is my assumption)

I am unsure how to make this work and any help would be appreciated.

All relative information
OS: Windows 11,
WSL OS: Ubuntu 22.04,
GPU: 7800xt,
CPU: Ryzen 7600

Comment: WSLg should cover this it CUDA certainly can be used.

Answer (score 2):

What you wish to do will not work (>98%).

WSL is a limited form of Virtual Machine and as such does not pass host hardware to the guest machine.

That is quite normal.

I did some reading on Hyper-V (I have a Hyper-V workstation) and I think it may be possible to pass some GPU hardware through to a Hyper-V Generation 2 machine.

You would need to research your own circumstance.

Also a different product from WSL is WSLg which is new and which may work. You would also need to research WSLg to see if it would work for you. It can run GUI apps but I quite sure (>95%) it will not run the Host GPU hardware. It might do the graphics you want.

Comment: WSLg is simply the graphical component of WSL that allows one to run GUI apps.  It won't help here.  The rest of the answer (as I previously upvoted) is completely correct.  Personally, I'd just suggest a rollback to the previous rev.

Comment: There was an open source article on WSLg that runs GUI apps.  I will make that clearer in  my answer